# CodeDom Compile The Type or Namespace Error

Tags: c#, namespaces, codedom

I have a program using WPF in C# that uses the .NET 4 Framework (Not Client Profile), and it compiles a source file called "Source.txt". However, whenever it compiles it I get this error "Error CS02345: The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)". No file is created.

When I checked the lines from the Source.txt file, these are the ones that are giving the error:

```
using System.Windows.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Management;
```

This is the code I'm using to compile it from the main program:

```
CompilerParameters Params = new CompilerParameters();
            Params.GenerateExecutable = true;
            Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            Params.OutputAssembly = ServerNameBox.Text;
            Params.CompilerOptions = " /target:winexe";    

            string Source = compileSource;
            CompilerResults Results = new CSharpCodeProvider().CompileAssemblyFromSource(Params, Source);

            if (Results.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (CompilerError err in Results.Errors)
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
            }
            else System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Compiled Program!");
```

As indicated in the code, I want this program to be compiled as a Windows Form / GUI Application (" /target:winexe");

If this information is not sufficient, please ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error clearly hints, you need to add `System.Windows.Forms.dll` to `ReferencedAssemblies`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks, that cleared that part up but now I am getting an error saying I need a static entry point. When I make my main method static, it's forcing me to make the rest of the variables and methods static as well. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @Hexo: The same way you write any other application

Comment: I'm sorry, could you clarify on your statement?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add at least the following references:

```
Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("PresentationFramework.dll");
Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Management.dll");
Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("PresentationCore.dll");
```

Also I don't believe **System.Windows.Linq** is an actual namespace. If you need LINQ it should be System.Linq and that is in System.Core.dll

Comment: PresentationFramework.dll & PresentationCore.dll could not be found. I believe in the compiled application I don't use System.Windows.Input so I just removed it. Thanks though.